# Плескаясь или плещась

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование

Подскажите, будьте добры, как правильно образовать деепричастие от слова "плескаться"?

Answer (score 1):

Обе формы — плеская и плещась — литературны и могут быть использованы равноправно.

Источник — Орфоэпический словарь русского языка под ред. Н. А. Еськовой.